# Cursor to auto insert Roll Numbers in student table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to go about auto populating student's `roll number` column in ascending order from 1,2,3... and so on  on assign button click  in the form ?

**TABLE**

[image]

How the cursor will be invoked?
I'm using stored procedures for all database operations.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
declare @studID int

declare rollCursor CURSOR FOR
select * from TESTING 

OPEN rollCursor
```

Comment: @Sarath I've reframed the question

Comment: You shouldn't use a cursor for this in the first place. I assume this must be for school. Tell your professor that a set based approach is much better. You could use ROW_NUMBER to accomplish this in a single statement. Of course it seems kind of silly because you already have ascending numbers in studID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single StudentId, just write in your procedure

```
 -- Where @StudendId will be parameter to your stored procedure
 SELECT * FROM TESTING
 WHERE StudId = @StudendId
```

Here is how you can use CURSOR. But note, CURSOR have performance issues. So use it rarely.

```
DECLARE @StudId INT
DECLARE @FName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ROLL INT

-- Here you declare which all columns you need to loop in Cursor
DECLARE rollCursor CURSOR FOR 
select * from TESTING
WHERE StudId = @StudendId
ORDER BY StudId;

OPEN rollCursor

-- Loop starts from here 
FETCH NEXT FROM rollCursor
INTO @StudId,@FName,@ROLL

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

     -- Select studentid one by one from the table
     SELECT * FROM TESTING
     WHERE StudId = @StudId

    -- Fetches next record and increments the loop
    FETCH NEXT FROM rollCursor
    INTO @StudId,@FName,@ROLL
END 

CLOSE rollCursor;
DEALLOCATE rollCursor;
```

**EDIT : 1** (Getting Row number for table)

If you need the result according to the `roll` then use the below query

```
-- This will bring you the records with roll number in ascending order
-- If you want in descending order just change ASC to DESC
SELECT studid,Fname,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY roll ASC) roll 
FROM StudId
```

**EDIT : 2** (Create identity field)

You need to set roll number column as `Identity field`, ie a column with an integer value which automatically increments value on new insertions.

Once you set the roll number column as `Identity field`, try with the below inserts

```
INSERT INTO TESTING(StudId,Fname)VALUES(10,'A')
INSERT INTO TESTING(StudId,Fname)VALUES(10,'A')
```

You will not select or include the roll number column in insert. It will automatically increment.

- [Click here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp) to view more on identity field

Comment: @SarathNo I wanted to insert values into roll number column automatically in database in ascending order on button click in the form studentid is not required I guess

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer if you got the result from the question you have asked. @saurabh64